# Dictionary translation ignored new language fallback

Tags: multilingual, language-fallback

Our SEO guy asked us to change the Spanish language code from es-MX to es-US for SEO reasons. We currently use the dictionary to handle a lot of translated strings, so it seemed to make the most sense to create es-US as a new language and have it fall back to es-MX (which in turn falls back to English for terms we don't have translated). For some reason, though, **the fallback skips right past es-MX and uses the English version.** If I create a new version of the dictionary item in the es-US language it works as expected. And, of course, it's been successfully falling back from es-MX to English already.

So far I've:

1. created the es-US language definition item [Master] System > Languages and set the fallback to es-MX
2. ensured that both item-level and field-level fallback is enabled in the configs
3. republished the site
4. reindexed everything in SOLR

The code simply calls `Sitecore.Globalization.Translate.TextByLanguage()` and stores the result on the view model, and I've confirmed that it's passing in the expected language code.

What am I missing?

*(Sitecore 8.1u3, SOLR 6.1.0)*

Comment: Seems like there is an issue with the cached dictionary file maybe. Try deleting `dictionary.dat` file from the `website/temp` folder and clearing the cache if necessary. Any reason you are using `TextByLanguage()` eather than `Sitecore.Globalization.Translate.Text("key")` and letting that do it's fallback thing?

Comment: No luck with that, unfortunately. At this point I've tried backing out the changes and I'm still getting English for everything. I'm stumped.

As to why we're using `TextByLanguage()`, it's because in this case the rendering is in Spanish but the rest of the page is English.